# executing kill() returns "operation not permitted". What is the workaround?

Tags: c, linux, apache, process, permissions

I have made progress in creating my own apache module along with a back-end module both in C and for linux. Most of the communication between the two modules is done with shared memory, but I'd like to use signals every now and then because I believe its faster than constantly checking a value of a variable.

My apache module runs under the username daemon and group name daemon. My back-end module runs under the username root and group name root. My back end module can detect when the signals happen, however in my apache module, I'm unable to send a kill signal. the kill command returns with "operation not permitted". and I can understand why.

What I want to know is if there's some function I could use in my back-end program that would allow the apache module to send signals to it without the back-end program looping continuously waiting for data from shared memory.

I'll be ok with functions that can change permissions to apply signals based on program process ID and/or username and/or group.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you could look at [some other ways of doing IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). Maybe you could use semaphores to signal data availability instead? You could also use a named pipe instead of shared memory to communicate which should automatically block on reads until data is available. Signal handlers are rather messy to write and probably isn't the best solution here.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the signal handler is a one-way street in my program. The apache handler sends a signal handler to the back-end when its ready to send over some more data.

Comment: In that case, I'd go for a named pipe to communicate. Your module can just dump data on the pipe and the back-end will process it as soon as it can.